# How to use HashMap as builder?

Tags: java, hashmap, command-pattern

i am trying to run some methods depending on the string parameters arriving me.
The idea is to activate and deactive some functions from a list of "Terminals".
The class is designed for a Command pattern, "doProcess" will be called in some time

My actual solution is awful, so I think about making a HashMap. For example:
map.put("Mail",activateMailsOfTerminals)

**But I dont know how to call the functions (activateMailsOfTerminals,deactivate...) dynamically depending on the list of string that comes on the constructor**

Thank you very much!

Bad solution:

```
public class ActionsActivator {

    Set < Terminal > terminals = new HashSet < > ();
    Set < String > activate = new HashSet < > ();
    Set < String > deactivate = new HashSet < > ();

    public ActionsActivator(Set < Terminal > filteredTerminals, Set < String > active, Set < String > deactive) {
        this.terminals = Map().getInstance().getTerminals;
        this.activate.addAll(activate);
        this.deactivate.addAll(deactivate);
    }

    public void doProcess() {
        if (hasElement(activate, "Mail")) terminals.forEach(terminal - > terminal.activateMails());
        if (hasElement(activate, "Register")) terminals.forEach(terminal - > terminal.activateRegisters());

        if (hasElement(deactivate, "Mail")) terminals.forEach(terminal - > terminal.deactivateMails());
        if (hasElement(deactivate, "Register")) terminals.forEach(terminal - > terminal.deactivateRegisters());
    }

    private Boolean hasElement(Set < String > list, String element) {
        return list.stream().anyMatch(elem - > elem.equals(element));
    }
}
```

Comment: So your current solution hard-codes invocations of the method `activateMails()` and `activateRegiters()`. Am I correct in understanding that you want to be able to pass in these functions to the constructor?

Comment: Not necessarily, I just dont want to check strings (hasElement and ifs). The best way would be calling the methods with just the string parameter list

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct in my understanding, you have a set of "terminals", and you want an object which when "activated" performs some method invocation/invocations on the terminals provided. The following should accomplish and demo that:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class CommandsDemo {

    public static class ActionsActivator{
        private Set<Terminal> terminals;
        private Set<Consumer<Terminal>> actionsToPerformOnTerminals = new HashSet<>();

        public ActionsActivator(Set<Terminal> terminals, Consumer<Terminal>... actionsForTerminals){
            this.terminals = terminals;
            actionsToPerformOnTerminals.addAll(Arrays.asList(actionsForTerminals));
        }

        public void doProcess(){
            for(Consumer<Terminal> action : actionsToPerformOnTerminals){
                terminals.stream().forEach(action);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Terminal{
        private final String name;

        public Terminal(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void activateMails(){
            System.out.println("Activated mail for: "+name);
        }
        public void activateRegisters(){
            System.out.println("Activated registers for: "+name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Terminal terminalA = new Terminal("terminalA");
        Terminal terminalB = new Terminal("terminalB");
        Terminal terminalC = new Terminal("terminalC");

        Set<Terminal> terminals = new HashSet<>();
        terminals.addAll(Arrays.asList(terminalA, terminalB, terminalC));

        ActionsActivator mailActivator = new ActionsActivator(terminals, (terminal)->terminal.activateMails());

        ActionsActivator registerActivator = new ActionsActivator(terminals, (terminal)->terminal.activateRegisters());

        ActionsActivator mailAndRegisterActivator = new ActionsActivator(terminals, 
                (terminal)->terminal.activateMails(),
                (terminal)->terminal.activateRegisters());

        System.out.println("Running mail activator");
        mailActivator.doProcess();

        System.out.println("Running register activator");
        registerActivator.doProcess();

        System.out.println("Running mail & register activator");
        mailAndRegisterActivator.doProcess();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Running mail activator
Activated mail for: terminalC
Activated mail for: terminalA
Activated mail for: terminalB
Running register activator
Activated registers for: terminalC
Activated registers for: terminalA
Activated registers for: terminalB
Running mail & register activator
Activated registers for: terminalC
Activated registers for: terminalA
Activated registers for: terminalB
Activated mail for: terminalC
Activated mail for: terminalA
Activated mail for: terminalB
```

The key thing that makes it possible for us to configure the command/commands to be invoked on each terminal is the generic [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) class, which represents the ability to be invoked with an instance of an object of the generically declared type as an argument. Ex:

```
Consumer<String> myConsumer = (str)->{System.out.println("Hello, "+str)};

myConsumer.accept("World");
myConsumer.accept("Venus");
myConsumer.accept("Mars");
```

prints:

```
Hello, World
Hello, Venus
Hello, Mars
```

So by passing in a series of `Consumer<Terminal>` objects which consume a `Terminal` and invoke a desired method on said `Terminal`s, we can make an  `ActionsActivator` which invokes a configurable method/methods on the provided terminals.

Comment: Its great! Thank very much for your time

Comment: Thanks. See edit for explanation of the key role played by `Consumer` in making this work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map:

```
private static Map<String, Consumer<Terminal>> activations = new HashMap<String, Consumer<Terminal>>() {{
    put("Mail", Terminal::activateMails);
    put("Register", Terminal::activateRegisters);
    // etc
}};
// similar for deactivate
```

Then to use:

```
public void doProcess() {
    activate.stream()
        .map(activations::get)
        .filter(a -> a != null)
        .forEach(a -> terminals.forEach(a));
    // similar for deactivate
}
```

This approach handles an arbitrarily large number of actions declaratively.